# Android Widget: RemoteViewsFactory does not display items correctly if getViewAt() method takes too long to execute

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I have an android widget that displays user thumbnails in a `GridView`. The code follows the android sample code for implementing a widget that shows a collection. Here is the code for my `getViewAt()` method:

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)
{
    if (mWidgetItems == null || position > mWidgetItems.size() - 1)
    {
        return getLoadingView();
    }
    WidgetUiUser user = mWidgetItems.get(position);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_grid_item);

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetLocation, user.getShortLocation());
    views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widgetLocation, View.VISIBLE);

    Intent srcIntent = ProfileActivity.createIntent(MyApplication.getInstance(), user, PageSourceHelper.Source.SOURCE_WIDGET);

    srcIntent.setAction(IntentRoutingActivity.getUniqueIntentAction()); //required for this activity to work properly
    views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widgetGridItemLayout, IntentRoutingActivity.createWidgetFillInIntent(srcIntent));

    // Fetch bitmap synchronously
    Bitmap bitmap = mImageFetcher.getBitmap(user.getImageUrl());
    views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widgetImage, bitmap);

    return views;
}
```

Everything works fine and all grid items get displayed correctly, providing the synchronous image load executes quickly.

However, if I run the app on a slow network where image downloads can take a few seconds, I quickly see that many of my grid items fail to load completely. I added some logcat output, and could see that the adapter fails to request the grid items that are not loading.

So for instance, my widget shows a 3x3 grid of users, and the entire `GridView` holds 80 or so. When working correctly, I see the adapter request around the first 20 grid items, and they all load correctly. When image loads are slow, I see the adapter request items 0, 3, 5, and 8 (for example, it varies) but no requests are made for any other items. If I start to scroll the `GridView`, more items start to get requested but many items still fail to request at all.

It seems that taking too much time in `getViewAt()` is somehow breaking the display behaviour, despite the fact that [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.html#getViewAt(int)) says it is fine to perform long operations in this method. Anyone seen this problem or know of a solution?

Comment: Just wondering, did you ever find a solution for this?  I am facing a similar problem where I am making a network call in `getViewAt()`, which sometimes causes the view to not load.

Comment: @BenSiver No, I was not able to resolve it. My workaround is that I do all my network operations from an overridden `RemoteViewsFactory.onDataSetChanged()` method, so that all the data I need is available when the adapter subsequently calls `getView()`. The big downside is a loooong pause when the widget refreshes before the adapter starts populating its content.

Comment: @JamesBusby upon fetching data in onDataSetChanged(), random items of my ListView are stuck at "Loading". Did you face the same too?